# Is LEI and Bloomberg Ticker one to one mapping. How about LEI, Bloomberg Ticker, Bloomberg ID, ISIN and CUSIP?

Tags: bloomberg, ticker-mapping

I am working on a project and need to map different IDs. Is LEI and Bloomberg Ticker one to one mapping? I can use Bloomberg formular =BDP(A1,"LEGAL_ENTITY_IDENTIFIER") to convert ticker "DUK US Equity" in excel A1 to LEI, but did not find formular to reverse it. So I suspect there will be a non-1-1 mapping issue here. How about LEI, Bloomberg Ticker, Bloomberg ID, ISIN and CUSIP? I think there must be one to multiple mapping among them, any one can sort it out?

Comment: Have a look at the LEI FAQ here: https://www.gleif.org/en/about-lei/questions-and-answers . The LEI is unique per legal entity, not per instrument. There is no 1:1 mapping between LEI and security

Comment: … and if a financial party has many subsidiaries (legal sense), then each will have their own LEI.

Comment: Bloomberg online chat rep said LEI and Bloomberg company ID are 1-1 mapping because they are both at company level. But we can not map LEI to ticker because ticker is at lower security level (instrument level in your word)

Answer (score 3):

Best to ask the help desk.
You can apply the following logic.

[image]

What the formula will return will reflect the settings you have on your `CNDF`  and `PDFQ` settings. You can do something like this though:

```
=BDP(BDP("DE0008404005"&" ISIN","EQY_FUND_TICKER")&" Equity","px last")
```

Alternatively, you can specify the exchange code after the ISIN (provided you know that).

```
=BDP("DE0008404005 GY"&" ISIN","px last")
```

There are lots of nuances; for example ISINs for options are not supported in the API (at least they were not last time I checked).

As mentioned in a comment, LEI are unique per entity. Therefore, it would not work to go from LEI to a single bond ISINs for example. It will work for tickers like `DUK US Equity` though, because this ticker is also unique. You can also get the entire bond chain and the associated ISINs (and other identifiers of interest) for a LEI

e.g.

- `=BDP("DUK US Equity","LEGAL_ENTITY_IDENTIFIER")` gives the LEI which is `I1BZKREC126H0VB1BL91`
- `=BDP(I1BZKREC126H0VB1BL91&" LEI","ULT_PARENT_TICKER_EXCHANGE")` gives `DUK US`
- `=BDP(A1&" LEI","CAST_PARENT_EQUITY_TICKER")` gives `DUK US Equity` directly, where A1 is the cell with the LEI ID in it.
- `=BCHAIN("DUK US EQUITY","Bonds")` to get the list of bonds that DUK US Equity issued. You can run `=BDP(A1;"ID_ISIN")` to get the associated ISIN for each bond. Given a bond ISIN, you can also retrieve LEI.

Comment: Are ISIN and CUSIP company level ID or instrument level ID?

Comment: ISINs/CUSIPs are share-class/issue level identifiers, as opposed to listing-level identifiers which contain a particular exchange or pricing source in Bloomberg parlance.

Comment: Based on hroptatyr's explanation above, could I say Bloomberg ticker will have an  ISIN/CUSIP mapping to it, but an ISIN/CUSIP may not have a Bloomberg ticker mapped to it?

Comment: All these identifiers are well defined. I suggest you look up the definitions online.